# printf() in background program

Tags: c, printf

I have a front-end X program, in this program , a background program a.out is called. In a.out, there are some `printf` sentences. I found the standard outputs are saved in `~/.xsession-errors`. Is it normal? I don't want to save these printf contents. Is there any method to avoid saving them except deleting `printf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`freopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen) function to redirect `stdout` to some other file, or to the null device if you'd rather not have any output:

```
// Discard all further output to standard output for the duration of the
// program (or until the next call to freopen()):
stdout = freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
```

Depending on how the child program is launched, you can also just redirect its stdout stream.  If you're launching it with `system(3)`, you can just use shell redirection:

```
system("./a.out args >/dev/null");
```

If you're launching it with a `fork()` and `exec()` pair, then you can redirect the stdout file descriptor in between the `fork()` and `exec()` to avoid changing anything in the parent process:

```
// Error checking omitted for expository purposes
pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid == 0)
{
    // Child process
    int fd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
    dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fd);
    execve("./a.out", argv, envp);
}
```

Comment: @Adam awsome explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities, by no means an exhaustive list:

1. When you run your child program, do so in such a way that standard output/error is sent to the bitbucket, such as `system ("myprog >/dev/nul 2>&1");`.
2. Include in that child program your *own* `printf` varargs-type function which basically does nothing. Provided that function is included before any attempt is made to link in the C runtime libraries, it will use your dummy one in preference.
3. Use `freopen` to redirect standard output and error to the same bitbucket.

Options 2 and 3 require changes to the child program which may or may not be desirable. The first option can be effected by only changing the parent program.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I had done this:
`#define printf(...)  ;`